Azure AI Search: What analyzer should I use for fields that contain a mixture of two languages?
I run a web resource in which we discuss Japanese reading material. Discussions are mostly in English, but of course contain Japanese words and phrases under discussion. As a result, much of the text content that I want to search over using Azure AI Search contains a mixture of Japanese and English, within the same field. For example, a user might ask a question like:
What does the へと mean in a sentence like スーパーへと走った?

I see in the Azure AI documentation that the case of having different fields in different languages is handled by attaching language-specific analyzers to each field. For example, a French language analyzer would be assigned to the French product description and an English language analyzer would be assigned to the English product description.
But I don't see anything that talks about intelligently handling a mixture of languages within the same field.
The Standard Lucene analyzer does a so-so job, but one challenge with Japanese is that many words can be represented in multiple ways. For example, in the sentence above, a user who is unfamiliar with kanji might write the last word はしった instead of 走った. The Lucene standard analyzer isn't smart enough to handle this.
I'd appreciate any pointers!

Yes what you said is correct. currently the multi language index is with different field names with specific language analyzer.
Whatever you are asking in the single field is not correctly supported,
according to this documentation the language analyzers are specific to target language and not for multiple language.
But what you can try is  Microsoft's English analyzer which can handle inflected and irregular word forms much better.
For you content use analyzer ja.microsoft.
Learn more about this here.
or
create separate field with Text Translation cognitive skill and perform query on that field.

Thank you for the reply. I will give Microsoft's English analyzer a try and see if it works better than the Lucene one. The idea of adding a text translation skill doesn't really work for me, because I want people to be able to search using the Japanese. People are asking questions about Japanese, in English. So the original Japanese needs to be preserved.

Ok try it.  If people uses japanese then you create new field with fully translated to japanese with your current field that is original field will be preserved.
